# Dojo Datagrid Scrolling "forgets" previous entries in IE 10

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo, scroll, xpages

I'm currently quite confused about a bug my datagrid is displaying. I am of the impression this bug has been a part of my code since the beginning at this point, but I have only started to notice it more recently.

Basically, after the grid is initially populated I can see all of my entries perfectly fine.

[image: Grid Works]

But then after I scroll downwards to the bottom of the list and wish to scroll back to the beginning of the list, the entries that were originally visible will usually (about half the time, more often than not if I scroll quickly) disappear (sometimes just half a row will disappear).

[image: Grid doesn't work]

If I scroll to the point where the missing rows (or just a few of them) are no longer visible again and then scroll back upwards, the rows that were hidden refresh and appear like they did in the first screen shot.

I know this is a somewhat odd problem and I hope I explained myself clearly enough. I have tried and been unable to replicate this result in Firefox and Chrome, so the issue seems to be restricted to IE (10 is what I am using). In this case I really need for this to work within this browser version as this is what is being suggested to our clients. I do not know if it is a factor, but this grid IS being displayed within an iframe.

Despite my efforts I have been unable to find much of anything online. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it behave this way in all browsers?

Comment: Good catch there. It only happens in IE, but IE is the browser that this application must run within. Any thoughts about what to do for IE?

Comment: I would edit the question and title, specifiy IE version because that makes a huge difference.  Use BrowserStack.com to check IE versions you don't have installed.

Comment: Thanks, I went ahead and made the changes. In this case I don't have much of a choice about using different versions of IE or any other browsers in general. IE 10 is one of only a few versions of IE that we officially support and so removing it from our list is not really an option.

Comment: I understand totally, I am in the same boat myself with IE :(